# Where's my Mad Hatter?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2017

The Mad Hatter description says:

> edit, or suggest an edit, 5 times in a single UTC day without commenting on the post

I've made five edits today on Mi Yodeya, where (as a moderator) I can confirm that I have never commented on the posts.  I got Werewolf Hunter with those edits (they were all old questions), but no Mad Hatter.  It's been more than an hour since the last edit.

The descriptions says without *commenting*, which I assume means *actual comments*.  I did give meaningful edit descriptions for most of them.  It doesn't mean "without writing an edit description", does it?

The edits: [1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55542/472), [2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/63874/472), [3](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66234/472), [4](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76388/472), [5](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77687/472) -- and, in case 5 is invalidated for being my own question, [6](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66271/472).

Am I missing something in the description, or are some hats slower than others to be awarded and I should wait longer?

**Update:** The above posts were all old (pre-Winterbash).  I then edited the tags to [one new question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87601/472) and got the hat.

What edits are eligible for this hat?

Comment: How long have you waited? From what I understand, it can take a while to be awarded.

Comment: @Catija the same set of edits should have qualified for both hats, if I understand them correctly.  (And no, this wouldn't be the first time that sort of thing has happened, one hat overlapping another.)  I got the other hat.  If editing my own post counts then it's been (at this writing) 48 minutes; if it doesn't, it's been 21.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've earned and received other hats since posting this, so I'm assuming that there's some requirement of this hat that I haven't met.  But I don't know what, since the description seems pretty clear.

Comment: @MonicaCellio when exactly did Winterbash begin? You sure you edited after it started? (back to drawing board)

Comment: Positive.  All edits were after the snowflake appeared, all UTC today (first day of Winterbash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is a lot simpler than one might think. Edits to your own posts *are* disqualified, but you see...

In the spirit of this year's "Off By One" Winter Bash theme, I figured I would update the method name of the query behind the Mad Hatter to say "Five" instead of "Six" like it did last year but neglect to update the query itself.

The elves in the back are urgently making extra hats to satisfy what is certain to be a higher demand for this hat now that the query's fixed, and they are not even mad about it.

Comment: Aha.  Thanks, and please give the elves some extra milk and cookies (or is it chocolate and whisky?) for the last-minute sprint.  I deliberately tested with one of my own posts for science, but then I added that sixth, but then there was still no headgear... thanks for explaining.